# I get ECONNREFUSED when npm i

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

i get this error when i do npm i

this happens only when in my proyect exist .npmrc file (i have proxy = null, and proxy its not needed)

```
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! FetchError: request to http://127.0.0.1:8081/repository/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/@nuxtjs/opencollective/-/opencollective-0.3.2.tgz failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8081
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:130:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR!     at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:454:9)
npm ERR!     at Socket.emit (node:events:539:35)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
npm ERR!     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8081
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:130:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR!     at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:454:9)
npm ERR!     at Socket.emit (node:events:539:35)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
npm ERR!     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect',
npm ERR!   address: '127.0.0.1',
npm ERR!   port: 8081,
npm ERR!   type: 'system'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

I dont understand why npm request to http://127.0.0.1:8081

Comment: you have registry set, run `npm config ls -l`

Comment: yes,

; "builtin" config from C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc

prefix = "C:\\Users\\xxxx\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"

; "global" config from C:\Users\jorda\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc

; registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/" ; overridden by project

; "project" config from C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\xxxxx\xxxx\Modules\xxxx-api\.npmrc

registry = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

; "cli" config from command line options

Comment: The part you redacted with 29 x's, *overridden by project*.. its not builtin. Run `npm config help` for instructions